# How to use DI when data needed to create a service needs ajax call

Tags: angular

So I have a `Principal` class, and I would like to make it available for DI using `providers`. This principal class has typical API (`isInRole`, `identity` etc.). The constructor of this class takes username, id, roles etc.

What I would like to achieve is to make it available via DI, e.g. for `@Component`'s and other `@Injectable` services... However, in order to create a single instance of this class, I need to call REST API and fetch information about a current user (it returns the id, roles, and some additional information), so information about the instance is not known until AJAX call ends.

First I was thinking about using `providers` with `useFactory`, but.... I'm not sure how to do it. Factory function would need to return a promise/observable and for DI I want to use `private principal: Principal`...

Any hints how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Please, provide details on your case. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Considering that the info you're getting from backend is not carved in stone and may change during app lifecycle, it most likely should be route resolver, not APP_INITIALIZER as existing answer suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute AJAX request before app starts (or components that use `Principal` class are instantiated). If there is chance that `Principal` AJAX call can return something like `not authorized` response - that also should be properly handled by `Principal\PrincipalService` internally.

You can do "app initialization" right from main `AppComponent` (that you provide to `.bootstrap()` function of your main `AppModule`), but that might be tricky, especially if you use `Principal` very early.

"Right" way to do that via `APP_INITIALIZER`... There are multiple examples on SO, so I don't want to copy/paste those. For example: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047

Please note, that `APP_INITIALIZER` **MUST** return `Promise`, not `Observable`.